# Search Activity never gets called

Tags: android

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.i3techs.mtricks">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchActivity" />
    <application
        android:name=".common.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".UserActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name=".service.FCMService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".service.FCMMessageService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AfterRegActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Search Activity :

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.search);
        doMySearch("hi");
        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
        }
    }

    public void doMySearch(String query)
    {
        Log.d("Search Query",query);
    }
}
```

In my main activity (one with the toolbar and search widget):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
return true;
}
```

I am not sure why "doMySearch" method is never get called.

Comment: make sure that `xml/searchable` has no hard-coding of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made similar search app in past. Here is my working code.
AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

MainActivity has Toolbar with search widget.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(component));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    return true;
}
```

And finally SearchActivity

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        tvSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSearchQuery);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void doMySearch(String query) {
        tvSearch.setText(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding  <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity" /> under MainActivity did the trick.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in onNewIntent instead of onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
 if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
    }
}
```

instead of

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.search);
    doMySearch("hi");
    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
    }
}
```